# Complex roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I know how to find the roots to the equation $z^n=w$, for $n \in \mathbb{R\setminus\{ 0\}}$ (by writing $w$ as $re^{i(\theta+2k\pi)}$), and taking the nth root of both sides, which I'm perfectly happy with, since $r^{1/n}$ is easy to find (with a calculator), as is $\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{n}$.

But what happens when we want to solve the equation $$z^t=w \tag{*}$$ for $t \in \mathbb{C}$?

e.g. how would one go about finding *all* roots of $$z^{2+3i}=1+i?$$

Obviously, it's not simply a case of writing $1+i$ in polar form and then taking the $(2+3i)$th root of $1+i$, since we don't know what $$\left| 1+i\right|^{1/({2+3i})}=\sqrt{2}^{1/(2+3i)}$$ is (or, even, that it exists).

Any ideas?

Short version: how do I find $t$th roots of a complex number for $t \in \mathbb{C}$?

Also, is there any way that we can determine how many roots this $(*)$ will have?

Comment: Short summary: Say you want $w^z$.  This is equal to $\exp\{z\cdot \ln w\}$, so the only interesting part is how to find $\ln w$; that is, how to find $x$ with $e^{x} = w$. The infinite family of $z^w$ is then completely determined by the infinite family of such $x$, all of which have the form $x = y + 2ik\pi$ for some fixed $y$ and arbitrary integer $k$.

Comment: (I have elaborated on my comment over at the other post.)